# Как добавить описание и написать снизу текст в скрипте PhotoSwipe?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Хочу установить скрипт галлереи PhotoSwipe с применением jQuery, применил описание с низу, с верху (добавил текст `<h3>Описание</h3>`) между тегами `</a><h3>Описание</h3><a>` [image: Когда не работает скрипт]. Но к сожалению после этого скрипт перестаёт работать и ничего не отрывается и не увеличивается. Страница к скрипт-галлереи:http://photoswipe.com/ Напишите мне почему при добавлении тегов для описания картинок скрипт сразу перестаёт работать и как сделать, что исправить чтобы можно бы было добавлять описание и при этом скрипт работал в нормальном режиме? на главной страницы photoswipe.ком есть галлерея изображений, если попробовать добавить описание в консоли для разработчиков (Google Developers console от браузеров) то она перестанет работать. Я закачал этот скрипт github.com/dimsemenov/photoswipe для своего сайта, всё подключил, только не смог понять как добавить описание к галерее. Весь день потратил и всё коту под муду... Заранее благодарю!

Answer (score 1):

Текст описания нужно заключить в тег `<figure>` и вставить все это внутри тега `<a>` рядом с `<img>`

```
<a> <img> <figure>Описания</figure> </a>
```